# How do I use cv to run database upgrades from the command line?

Tags: upgrade, drush, cv

I'd like to run the database upgrades from the command line. I know I can do with with `drush civicrm-upgrade-db` but I'd like to know a way to do it in a CMS-agnostic way (that will work for Wordpress and Joomla).

I see there is `cv ext:upgrade-db` which claims to "Apply DB upgrades for any extensions". Is there a corresponding `cv` command for CiviCRM core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cv upgrade:db` command from https://github.com/civicrm/cv/pull/2 was recently merged for v0.2.3. This revision hasn't been broadly deployed or tested yet, but it provides a richer upgrade experience:

- By default, there's a progress indicator.
- With `-vvv`, you can get a detailed report/log of the upgrade steps as they execute.
- With `-vvv --dry-run`, you can see a detailed preview of the upgrade steps.
- With `--retry` or `--skip`, you can resume after an upgrade failure.
- With `--quiet`, you can limit output to particularly interesting information.

I've found that `-vvv` and `--dry-run` are helpful when developing patches for the `civicrm-core` upgrade logic, and they may also be helpful with large or temperamental upgrades.

(**Note**: PR #2 also anticipates several more subcommands for identifying/downloading upgrades and for reporting successes and failures. However, these are not live at time of writing)

Answer (score 2):

That would be nice, but I am afraid it is not there (yet). When you lookup the [list of cv commands](https://github.com/civicrm/cv/tree/master/src/Command) in de source on GitHub, you will not find this command.

However, using the `drush` [source code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/drush/civicrm.drush.inc) as inspiration you can create a small script

```
<?php
  $codeVer = CRM_Utils_System::version();
  $dbVer = CRM_Core_BAO_Domain::version();
  if (version_compare($codeVer, $dbVer) == 0) {
     echo "You are already upgraded to CiviCRM $codeVer \n";
  } else {
     $upgradeHeadless = new CRM_Upgrade_Headless();
     $result = $upgradeHeadless->run();
     echo "Upgrade outputs:\n" . $result['text'] . "\n";
  }
```

And run it with the `cv scr <script.php>`